# Resize the super view with respect to the sub view in swift3

Tags: swift3, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

**How to resize the UIVIEW according to it's subview(Label)?**

[My Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5viX.png)

I have a label inside a UIVIEW. I want the label to take maximum number 5 lines and the label size should be according to the number of lines (it may be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) and the view should resize automatically according to the size of label in swift3.

How to make it please help me.

Comment: please add screenshot of your design ,it will help us more to explain you

Comment: file:///Users/ShiftuTechnology/Downloads/IMG_108FABC47AB1-1.jpeg

Comment: there is no file on this link

Comment: file:///Users/ShiftuTechnology/Downloads/IMG_108FABC47AB1-1.jpeg             here i have taken 4 views . one view is the super view of the label("chicken roll1"). these 4 views are in stack view. i want the view(which is the super view of label ("chicken roll1")) will be resized according to the lable("chicken roll1").  for example - the view height should be equal to height of "chicken roll1" lable

Comment: how to add image in comment ?

Comment: add image in your question update it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ynG6.png                                                                       Here is the image ,  i want to work on with

Comment: @Tapan edit ur question and add image there.

Comment: I have added the image.Please see it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Equal height constraints from uiview to uilabel and set constraints multiplier from value 1 to 5 as per your requirements.